# How to return all KeyValuePairs of a IDictionary C#

Tags: c#, generics, idictionary

I want to write a method which return all key value pairs containing in a `IDictionary` as Map.EntrySet() does in java.

I tried as:

For example we define `IDictionary` as:

```
private IDictionary<T, MutableInt> _map = new Dictionary<T, MutableInt>();
```

The method as:

```
public KeyValuePair<T, MutableInt> KeyValuePairSet()
{
   return KeyValuePair<T, MutableInt>(_map.Keys, _map.Values);
}
```

while returning statement, the error raised is:

`KeyValuePair<T, MutableInt> is a type but used like a variable`

How can this method be implemented?

Comment: return **new** KeyValuePair<T, MutableInt>... However, this will also fail. What exactly do you expect to get in return? a List<KeyValuePair>? an array?

Comment: I actually want to get in return same as what if `_map.entrySet()` returns in Java

Comment: You said that already, but though it may come as a surprise, not all c# programmers actually knows Java as well...

Comment: This sounds like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what are you doing that you require re-crateing that method. There may be better ways to get the job you are trying to done.

Comment: But I also now mentioning here that `_map.entrySet()` in Java returns same as KeyValuePair in C#

Comment: @Taufel no it does not, `_map.entrySet()` returns a **set** of `KeyValuePair`, not a single one. [`KeyValuePair<K, V>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx) maps to `Map.Entry<K,V>` in java. So therefor the `Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>` the function `entrySet()` returns maps to a `ISet<KeyValuePair<K, V>>` However, please explain *why* you need to  to this, there extremely is likely better ways to do what you are trying to do in C#.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I really means that you right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it is fairly easily, because `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` implmentents the interface `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` all you need to do is declare your HashSet and pass the dictionary in because `HashSet<T>` has a constructor that takes in a `IEnumerable<T>` as its parameter.

```
public ISet<KeyValuePair<T, MutableInt>> KeyValuePairSet()
{
   return new HashSet<KeyValuePair<T, MutableInt>>(_map);
}
```

Comment: In fact, depending on how OP is planning to use the "set", he may not need the method at all.  He may not realize that he can probably just use `_map` directly in a `foreach` loop for example.

Comment: it is almost certainly not the right thing to do to return a hash-set of the key/value pairs; to use it directly, you'd need to know both key and value, in which case the original dictionary is moot - you probably want a *list*, or : just a dictionary!

Answer (score 3):

Given:

```
private IDictionary<T, MutableInt> map = new Dictionary<T, MutableInt>();
```

If you want to return `IEnumerable` of `KeyValuePair`s:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, MutableInt>> get_pairs()
{
   return map;
}
```

If you want to return `KeyValuePair` of keys and values of `map`:

```
KeyValuePair<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<MutableInt>> get_pair()
{
   return new KeyValuePair<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<MutableInt>>(map.Keys, map.Values);
}
```

If you want to return `HashSet` of `KeyValuePair`s:

```
ISet<KeyValuePair<T, MutableInt>> get_pairs()
{
   return new HashSet<KeyValuePair<T, MutableInt>>(map);
}
```

Comment: He wants the behavior of [`Map.EntrySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()), which would output a `ISet<KeyValuePair<T, MutableInt>>`.

Comment: `KeyValuePair<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<MutableInt>>` is just horrible; I can't think of any occasion that would be preferable to just returning the dictionary

Comment: @Riad--statement `return new HashSet(map);` in your last method raises an error i.e. `requires one type of argurment`

Comment: Thanks @Taufel, fixed. I omitted specification for HashSet. It is needed to avoid compiling ambiguity.